# Send data from Backend JS to Renderer - Electron

Tags: electron, backend

I have been trying to send data generated in backend JS to front end. The event is called when a message in person sends messages in discord channel.

I am basically new to this Electron.

discord-api.js:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author === client.user) {
        return
    }

    console.log(message.content)
})
```

I need to sends the message to the renderer home.js (Renderer connected with home.html).

[image]

Any way how?

There is no BrowserWindow here, so webContents did not work.

Need a direct way to send the data from backend to frontend.

Comment: What do you mean when you say there is "no BrowserWindow here"? Isn't `render.js` where you wish to send the data to loaded in by `home.html`, which I assume would be displayed in a browser window?

Comment: No the data is generated in the backend not in render.js. If the data is in render.js, it would have been easy. I have actually figured it out. What I had done is, I have created a database and store the data there and I use a callback function in render.js to retrieve the data from the backend.